# Groupby mean ignoring zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a pivot table which has this structure :

```
        correl
        stock_b      AAAA    CCCC    DDDD
stock_a date            
AAAA    2018-01-02   0.00    0.00    0.00
        2018-01-10   0.00    0.00    0.00
        2018-01-15   0.00   69.45   69.14
        2018-01-31   0.00    0.00    0.00
BBBB    2018-01-02   0.00   43.29   67.38
        2018-01-14   0.00    0.00    0.00
        2018-01-15  50.16   42.74   67.47
        2018-01-31   0.00   42.74   67.47
```

I would like to group by `stock_a` and take the mean value, ignoring zero. It would look like :

```
         correl
stock_b  AAAA    CCCC    DDDD
stock_a         
AAAA     0.00   69.45   69.14
BBBB    50.16   42.92   67.44
```

`df.groupby('stock_a').mean()` take in account the 0 and the value is not what i would like to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `groupby` and `mean`:

```
print (df[df.ne(0)].groupby("stock_a").mean().fillna(0))
   
          AAAA       CCCC   DDDD
stock_a                         
AAAA      0.00  69.450000  69.14
BBBB     50.16  42.923333  67.44
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 'custom' aggregate function for your groupby using `agg`. This can be a lambda function, but for readability, I prefer a proper function like this:

```
def mean_excluding_zero(l):
    nonzero = [elem for elem in l if elem != 0]
    return sum(nonzero) / len(nonzero)

df.groupby('stock_a').agg(mean_excluding_zero)
```